# Save Image From JLabel Without JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing

I want to save the image FROM JLabel to Folder without JFileChooser. I have a method like this

```
private void SaveImage(){
        Icon icon = lblPhoto.getIcon();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        ImageIcon ImageIcon = (ImageIcon)lblPhoto.getIcon();
        OutputStream out = null;
        int size =0;
        Image Image = ImageIcon.getImage();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("\\RekamMedis\\Photo\\"+txtNama.getText().trim()+".jpg");
            byte[] b = new byte[size];
            out.write(b);
            ImageIO.write((RenderedImage)Image, "jpg", out);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(lblPhoto.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
```

But this method show the empty image.jpg or other format. What is the best solution for this problem??

Comment: Variable names (and method names) should NOT start with an upper case character. Notice how the forum highlights your code. It thinks all your variable names are class names which makes your code difficult to read. Follow Java conventions.

Comment: (1-) How many times do you need to be asked to follow conventions for naming Java variables and methods??? You were also asked to do so in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52093797/select-image-from-jfilechooser-and-view-it-on-jlabel. If you want people to help, then make an effort to make the posted code readable!!!

Comment: `byte[] b = new byte[size];
out.write(b);` means you're saving a byte array of size `size` filled with zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to bounce around a few ideas but doesn't seem to achieve anything

This...

```
ImageIcon ImageIcon = (ImageIcon)lblPhoto.getIcon();
```

and this...

```
byte[] b = new byte[size];
out.write(b);
```

and this...

```
ImageIO.write((RenderedImage)Image, "jpg", out);
```

All look like bad ideas.  You shouldn't be blindly casting objects and I don't know why you're using `FileOutputStream` to write an empty array of bytes (which is of 0 bytes length) to the file anyway.

A more "simplistic" approach would be to paint the `Icon` (which you have/know) to a `BufferedImage` (which supports `RenderedImage`) and then write that, via `ImageIO` to a `File`, something like...

```
Icon icon = lblPhoto.getIcon();
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
icon.paintIcon(lblPhoto, g2d, 0, 0);
g2d.dispose();

File file = new File("\\RekamMedis\\Photo\\"+txtNama.getText().trim()+".jpg");
ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", file);
```

I'd also add a check to see if `icon` is `null` or not, just because, they might not have a photo assigned